# A book sits on a table. What is the net force of air pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, everyday-life, air

An elementary problem asks,

> A book is at rest on a table top. In what direction is the net force
>   of air pressure on the book?

Is this a meaningful question, and if so, what's the answer?

If we imagine that the book and table are completely smooth, there's no air between the book and table. Then the air pressure from above the book creates a large net downward force of hundreds of pounds. (This will be countered by an upward force from the table.)

On the other hand, if we imagine that due to the rough nature of the book and table, there is some air between the book and the table at most places, maybe there is enough air underneath the book to provide a net pressure force that is upwards. The scale height of the atmosphere is about 10^4m, so a 1cm book needs to have less than 1 part in 10^6 in contact with the table to have net upward force from air pressure.

How realistic are these approaches? Do we need a molecular view of the book, table, and air to understand the situation? For a typical, everyday book and table, is it meaningful to ask what direction the net force of air pressure pushes?

Comment: It is meaningful; And the direction is(no surprise) downward!

Comment: The point(I think) is that we usually start with a book in the air, and then we put it down on the table(so there is more than often some air trapped under the book, with somewhat higher pressure to cancel the pressure from above). $ \\ \\ $However, if we start with the book on the table, and then we add the atmosphere; then we will have an obvious downward force from the air!

Comment: This is why a 1kg of lead is heavier than 1kg of feathers :)

Comment: @Ali The direction of [this force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy#Buoyancy_of_air) is upward because there's always air between the book & the table.

Comment: If there was no air between the book and the table, the book would stick to the table, just like a vacuum sticker.

Comment: Air pressure will also apply a force on the table upwards ;)

Comment: @Sawl Of course you can neglect the weight of the displaced air (on the condition of being clear about it). It is
negligible when other more interesting effect can be significantly stronger. The effect
of atmosperic pressure is isotropic and can be observed in all
directions, and it can be very strong (fortunately for water pumps, as
noticed by Pascal). Boyancy of dense objects in air is very weak
relative to weight, always upward oriented, and frequently neglected by
all, including Galileo (afaik), and people using Roberval balances in
markets (that is getting rare).

Comment: @babou I actually assume that buoyancy is the point of the question "what direction is the net force of air pressure on the book?". OP's pressure-difference approach should be plausible, I only add some data to it to convince him.... Hmm, other interesting effects? Note that the 'suction cup' effect (on typical books, not rubber ones) is actually a dynamic effect, and the book was at rest in the original question, so its effect is zero.

Comment: @Sawl Buoyancy is an obvious and weak effect, very small compared
to the book weight, so that I assumed that
it was uninteresting in this case and I looked for other effects.  Now
I see the suction cup effect as a static effect. It stops as soon as
the book is moved. Actually you may get the plastic salad bowl effect
-- when the bowl looks heavier than it is, and the salad flies -- as
the force to detach the book far exceeds the force to simply hold
it. It is interesting to analyze what happens as the book leaves the
table, as you did. I wonder if the book bottom becomes measurably
colder.

Comment: @babou Just focus on the question! The elementary problem the OP posted, asks for the net force of _air pressure_, so it is important to exclude other forces (such as weight) even though they are gazillion orders of magnitude bigger than air pressure.

Comment: @Sawl You have a point. Actually you are probably right to stick to
that point of view. That is what is often expected from an
academic perspective, and doing otherwise may get you into trouble.
The teachers here might have an opinion more informed than mine. On
the other end, my formal academic time is long past and I only (or
mostly) look at what seems interesting or unexpected in a problem, as
I often do professionally.
I may get into "trouble" on the site for that, i.e. get downvoted,
but I can survive it, though I hate it when I do not know why. Is that
an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Sawl Could you be more precise as to the wrong assumption I reasoned
from ?  The question was about a book at rest. Hence dynamic effects
are not involved.  The suction effect you describe is a dynamic
effect (viscosity). I doubt you feel anything, or measure anything with a
dynamometer if you try to lift the rough paper book slowly. Whereas,
the effect I describe will be felt and measured independently of the
lifting speed (provided the book is rigid). It is even possible to
raise another object that way (card playing trick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How realistic are these approaches? Do we need a molecular view of the book, table, and air to understand the situation?

It is realistic. There are no need to consider the molecular nature of air.

See http://www.nanovea.com/Application%20Notes/paperroughness.pdf. According to their data, the typical length in paper's surface variation is in order of $10^{-5}$ meters, while air's mean free path is $6.8\times 10^{-8}$ m (at room temperature, ambient pressure.) That means the room below the book cannot be thin enough to prevent significant amount of air sitting there (Babou actually reasoned his/her answer from wrong assumptions)

Considering the deformation of 'peaks' of surface of cover of a (heavy) book, it is likely that the book is in contact with the table more than 1 part in $10^6$. Therefore I'd guess that the net force is downward.

However, our static approach cannot be used if someone is picking up the book. S/he may experience the 'suction cup' effect (described in Babou's answer) when the book s/he lifted feels like "glued" to the table at one instant. When the book is lifted, air trapped below the book experiences a rapid, adiabatic expansion. Viscosity prevents surrounding air from entering the expanding room (below the book's surface) so rapidly. Hence the pressure below the book drops, and pressure from air above the book wins.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the data. I'm consistently surprised at how things I thought I understood long ago can still twist me around until somebody helps show me how to think about it.

Comment: You cannot have it both way. Either the force exists, or it does not.
If it exists, as you first state, regarding paper contact, then you
have to overcome it before you move anything. It is true that a flexible
object may slowly deform to let air and pressure in,
but that is another issue, not incompatible with what I said.  I was
simply not specific about the the amount, and I did choose to neglect
buoyancy. But your dynamic justification of suction effet is irrelevant.
I would not be sure about other minute
effects,though you may well be right. Still, very small scale often offers
surprises.

Comment: Thinking further about your analysis of paper surface, I was wondering
about measuring the forces. I do not know how to do it, but there is
one experiment that goes your way. It does happen that light paper may
stay like glued to the underside of a book. This is probably a
consequence of what you describe. The paper acts as a very light
tabletop that is lifted with the book.

Answer (score 3):

We will assume that the book and the air
layer between book and table are thin enough, possibly no air in places, and the book dense
enough (very important), so that atmospheric pressure may be
considered constant, i.e., so that its variation can be neglected.

In a nutshell, the answer is that there is a downward force from atmospheric pressure. It can be null. The reason is that the pressure on the sides balances. The pressure
downward applies to all of the top of the book.  The pressure upward may apply to only part of the bottom surface of the book. This can be seen with a book that has a rubber cover and is placed on a glasstop.

Essentially the you have a suction cup effect that may make it very difficult to lift the book, much more than its weight would warrant. It can actually be measured by a dynamometre. So the net effect of atmospheric pressure is downward.

Actually it can be upward if you use atmospheric pressure to "glue" your book to the underside of a glass tabletop (better use one with a rubber cover).

It is the same phenomenon that happens when you need extreme force to pull the plug
from a full bathtub.  And it is also what has drowned a few people in
swimming pools.  They could not detach themselves from an open water
exit at the bottom.

Note that you can also have trapped bubbles of compressed air that have the opposite effect.

I had made a complete model of the system (as you started discussing details), but I realized that was not what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Is the book and table one object or two?

Either way, the large downward force on the top surface is matched by an equal force on the bottom surface.

If it weren't, the object(s) would experience acceleration.

Comment: *the large downward force on the top surface is matched by an equal force on the bottom surface*. What about the buoyancy?

Comment: @metacompactness: touche'. I ignored the weight of the objects, and the weight of the displaced air.

Comment: You cannot neglect the weight of the displaced air if the question is "_in what direction is the net force of air pressure on the book?_"