# Does atmospheric pressure have a net contribution to this FBD (free body diagram)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, free-body-diagram

[image]

Pressure acting on the left and right sides of the block counteract

Comment: I'd add arrows representing the sideways forces, even though they cancel.  (Note that the Force Concept Inventory has a similar problem, but the "correct" solution includes atmospheric pressure *under* the block as well, giving a bouancy force.  I always thought that that "correct" solution was bogus. )

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191115/2451

Comment: There is a buoyant force from the atmosphere that is equal to the weight of the air that is displaced.  This force is normally MUCH smaller than mg, so it usually is not included in a free body diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Atmospheric pressure will just act as an extra "weight" for your object, such that

$$
\left| N \right| = \left| mg \right| + \left| P_0 A_{top} \right|
$$

Think of the pressure from above as just being the weight of all the air stacked on top of the box.

From the sides you have just got

$$
\left| P_0 A_{left} \right| = \left| P_0 A_{right} \right|
$$

so this cancels and does not contribute any net force.

Comment: This is true if there is a tight seal at the surface of contact, and may be partially true if there is a (or a set of) locally tight seal that doesn't cover the whole surface of contact. That said, for most ordinary object in contact with ordinary surfaces the conditions for tight seal are not met, so the simplicity of this answer is probably misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if there are air between the squared block and the floor. If there is even an small joint with air, as when a box is on the floor, atmospheric pressure is acting from all sides of the box and the downward pressure from upper side nearly balances the upward pressure from bottom side. Therefore atmospheric pressure doesn't have a net effect.

On the other hand, if we can exclude air from the bottom side, as in a suction cup, then downward pressure is unbalanced and atmospheric pressure should be taken in account in that free body diagram.

And just as a side note: In first paragraph I said that upward and downward forces *nearly* balance each other. In fact there is a small difference and that difference is the buoyancy of the solid in air. Anyway, such buoyancy is usually so small compared with weight that can be safely ignored unless we are dealing with very light objects - like balloons.

Answer (score -2):

The free body diagram is accepted but one should remember to make lines of forces close to each other for forces acting on same direction.As usually it can be seen in books like HRW.

Comment: Technically?   Technically, each force gets it's own arrow.  Don't represent two forces by one arrow.

Comment: Arrows that cancel out are usually misconstucted to avoid confusion.source wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry for my answer though it is not exactly incorrect moreover i just would have meant that lines must be drawn from centre of the object.Thanks for taking it to my notice.

Comment: I have edited my answer if its wrong please explain else voting it back to zero will be my humble request thanks.

Comment: HRW is what, exactly?

Comment: Halliday resnick and walker